# Why I am getting typeerror for Histogram of Oriented Gradient (HOG) feature in scikit-image?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I am trying to generate histogram of magnitude. I see below error for the example from docs.

```
File "/Users/air/Projects/cs512-f17-project/SIFT/hog.py", line 10, in <module>
    cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualize=True)
TypeError: hog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'visualize'
```

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_hog.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.feature import hog
from skimage import data, color, exposure


image = color.rgb2gray(data.astronaut())

fd, hog_image = hog(image, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(32, 32),
                    cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualize=True)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax1.axis('off')
ax1.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax1.set_title('Input image')
ax1.set_adjustable('box-forced')

# Rescale histogram for better display
hog_image_rescaled = exposure.rescale_intensity(hog_image, in_range=(0, 0.02))

ax2.axis('off')
ax2.imshow(hog_image_rescaled, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax2.set_title('Histogram of Oriented Gradients')
ax1.set_adjustable('box-forced')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`visualize` parameter was introducted in `scikit-image=0.14dev`, and is meant to substitute the old parameter `visualise`. In `scikit-image=0.13.x` there is no parameter `visualize` (http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/api/skimage.feature.html?highlight=hog#skimage.feature.hog). Please, make sure you are looking at the `stable` version of the documentation.